# error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i want to create a form which has 2 dropdown, the second dropdown will be trigger by the first dropdown without reload the page, after the first dropdown selected/change, so i decide to use ajax

instead trigger the second dropdown it is returning this error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  add_product.php:1

error on above happen if i use google chrome
and this the error when i use firefox with firebug

> **Warning**:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/portofolio1/dd-multiple.php** on line **15**
>   
>   **Warning**:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/portofolio1/dd-multiple.php** on line **16**
>   {"data":null}
>
> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
>   script.js (line 34, col 26)

this is script.js file

```js
function AjaxFunction(id1,id2)
{   
    alert(id1);
    var httpxml;
    try
    {
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        httpxml=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e)
    {
    // Internet Explorer
        try
        {
            httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            try
            {
                httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e)
            {
                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    
    function stateck(){
        if(httpxml.readyState===4)
        {
            var myarray = JSON.parse(httpxml.responseText);

            // Before adding new we must remove previously loaded elements
            for(j=document.getElementById(id2).length-1;j>=0;j--)
            {
                document.getElementById(id2).remove(j);
            }

            for (i=0;i<myarray.data.length;i++)
            {
                var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
                optn.text = myarray.data[i].subcategory;
                //optn.value = myarray.data[i].subcat_id;  // You can change this to subcategory 
                optn.value = myarray.data[i].subcategory;  

                document.getElementById(id2).options.add(optn);
            } 

        }
    }


    var str='';
    var s1ar=document.getElementById(id1);
    for (i=0;i< s1ar.length;i++) { 
        if(s1ar[i].selected){
            str += s1ar[i].value + ','; 
        }
    } 
    //alert (s1ar);

    var str=str.slice(0,str.length -1); // remove the last coma from string
    //alert(str);


    /////
    //alert(str);
    var url="dd-multiple.php";

    url=url+"?cat_id="+str;
    url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
    //alert(url);
    httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateck;
    httpxml.open("GET",url,true);
    httpxml.send(null);
}
```

this my add_product.php file

```html
<?php
    require_once './model/functions.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
                
 </head>
 <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="center-block" style="width: 130px;">
                        <h3><strong>Add Book</strong></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <form method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="kategori" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Kategori : </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kategori" name="kategori" placeholder="pilih kategori">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="tipeIklan" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Tipe Iklan : </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="genderRadioOptions" id="tipeIklan" value=1>Dicari
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="genderRadioOptions" id="tipeIklan" value=0>Dijual
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="genderRadioOptions" id="tipeIklan" value=2>Disewakan
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="genderRadioOptions" id="tipeIklan" value=3>Jasa
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="judul" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Judul : </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="judul" name="judul" placeholder="Judul iklan anda">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="deskripsi" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Deskripsi : </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            
                            <textarea id="deskripsi" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="harga" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Harga(Rp.) : </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="harga" name="harga" aria-describedby="helpBlock" placeholder="cukup tuliskan angka">
                            <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block">Contoh: 2000</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="kondisi" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Kondisi : </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="genderRadioOptions" id="kondisi" value=0>Bekas
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="genderRadioOptions" id="kondisi" value=1>Baru
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="provinsi" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Provinsi : </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <select  id="provinsi" name="s1[]" class="form-control" onchange="AjaxFunction('provinsi', 'kota')">
                                <option>select one</option>
                                <?php
                                    
                                    $provinsi_set = find_all_province();
                                    while($provinsi = mysqli_fetch_assoc($provinsi_set)){    
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $provinsi["id"];?>"><?php echo $provinsi["nama"]; ?></option>
                                <?php
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="kota" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Kota : </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <select  id="kota" name="s2[]" class="form-control">
                                
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="foto" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Upload Foto : </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            
                                <img src="uploads/raditya.jpg" alt="" width="140" height="140" class="img-thumbnail">
                                <img src="uploads/Kambing_Jantan_buku_2.jpg" alt="" width="140" height="140" class="img-thumbnail">
                                <img src="uploads/raditya.jpg" alt="" width="140" height="140" class="img-thumbnail">
                                
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-4">
                        <button type="button" id="registrationbutton" class="btn btn-default">Tayangkan!</button>
                    </div>    
                
                </form>
            </div>
            
           
            <script src="jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/script.js"></script>
        <?php close_connection(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

the problem dissapear when i remove this code `onchange="AjaxFunction('provinsi', 'kota')"`

and this is my dd-multiple.php in case someone asking for it

```html
<?php
    @$cat_id=$_GET['cat_id'];
    
    $mn=split(",",$cat_id); // creating array 
    while (list ($key, $val) = each ($mn)) { 
        
        if(!is_numeric($val)){  // checking each element 
            echo "Data Error ";
            exit;
        }
    }
      
    global $id_mysql;
    $query = "SELECT nama,id FROM KOTA WHERE id_prov IN ($cat_id)";
    $row = mysqli_query($id_mysql, $query);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($row);
    
    $main = array('data'=>$result);
    echo json_encode($main);
?>
```

Comment: Do you have `<script>` tags in your JavaScript file? If so, that's the problem.

Comment: No, i didnt have. My .js file is on above

Comment: Are you sure the file ha the `.php` extension?

Comment: Are you sure the file ha the .php extension? - yes im sure

Comment: @Pointy , i already put newest error i had from firebug on above

Comment: @VaMoose i already put newest error i had from firebug on above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get that error is because your `mysqli_query` is incorrect.

You have your `link` which is null. Your `link` should be the connection to your database, ie:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "database");
$query = "SELECT nama,id FROM KOTA WHERE id_prov IN ($cat_id)";
$row = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($row);

$main = array('data'=>$result);
echo json_encode($main);
```